# JAX-WS Client: Cannot create Service Object (org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype)

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws, tomcat9, cxf-client

I have a CXF Soap Web-service which in turn invokes another external SOAP web-service. I've deployed the code to Tomcat 9 running with JDK 11. I'm getting the below exception when i'm trying to create the Service class to invoke the external Service. I tried creating service object in both ways mentioned below.

```
//Method 1: 
service = Service.create(url, qname);

//Method 2:
service = new SearchService(url, qname);
```

The runtime exception thrown is below:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error while searching for service [javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider]
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:61)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:58)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.firstByServiceLoader(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:70)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:89)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:96)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:765)
    ...
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1236)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.firstByServiceLoader(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:63)
    ... 61 more
```

Need help resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Have you found the answer? @Peter Freiberge as well